# Symfony files which are included in CSS are not found when using assetic

Tags: css, symfony, twig, assetic

I'm using Symfony with Twig and I use assetic. The problem is that my CSS file includes other CSS files like that:

```
@import url(ie8.css);
@import url(blocks.css);
@import url(plugins.css);
@import url(app.css);
```

And these files are not found when webpage is displayed.
Same happens with fonts and images. How do I solve this?

I have to mention that I load css files like that:

```
        {% stylesheets
        '@BaseBundle/Resources/public/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        '@BaseBundle/Resources/public/css/style.css'
        filter='cssrewrite'
        %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets) and [this section as well](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter):

> Notice that in the original example that included JavaScript files, you referred to the files using a path like `@AppBundle/Resources/public/file.js`, but that in this example, you referred to the CSS files using their actual, publicly-accessible path: `bundles/app/css`. You can use either, except that there is a known issue that causes the `cssrewrite` filter to fail when using the `@AppBundle` syntax for CSS stylesheets.

and

> When using the `cssrewrite` filter, don't refer to your CSS files using the `@AppBundle` syntax. See the note in the above section for details.

The `cssrewrite` filter is crucial as it will rewrite those `url()` CSS paths that you defined in your stylesheets. By using the `@AppBundle` syntax, this no longer happens. You need to load CSS files like this:

```
{% stylesheets
    'bundles/base/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    'bundles/base/css/style.css'
    filter='cssrewrite'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Note the paths may not be 100% correct (it depends on your bundle name). You should double check by performing `php app/console assets:install` and look in your `web/` folder.